# How to draw a dice using turtle python

Tags: python, dice, python-turtle

I'm struggling to make the dice using **turtle** graphics library in python but I'm stuck. Below is the image of the dice I have to make.

[image: A demo of the dice I'm looking for]

Can anybody please give me a chunk of code for the **Dice**? Thanks a lot

Comment: I have found the code on this [link](https://trinket.io/python/d0edbc400c) but the code is 170+ lines, if you have any shorter code idea, please help

Comment: have you gone through this ?
https://www.codespeedy.com/python-program-to-create-a-dice-game-using-turtle/

Comment: @Alex I don't need the actual game. I just need to make the dice with the dots as shown in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a function like this:

```
import turtle as tg

def dice(face,side=100,color='blue',width=2):
    tg.color(color if face else 'white')
    tg.width(width)
    tg.pendown()
    for _ in range(4):
        tg.forward(side)
        tg.left(90)
    faces = { 0: [(1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(3,3),(5,1),(5,3),(5,5)],
              1: [(3,3)],
              2: [(1,1),(5,5)],
              3: [(1,1),(3,3),(5,5)],
              4: [(1,1),(1,5),(5,1),(5,5)],
              5: [(1,1),(1,5),(3,3),(5,1),(5,5)],
              6: [(1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(5,1),(5,3),(5,5)] }
    x,y     = tg.pos()
    offset  = side/15
    dotSize = (side-2*offset)/7
    tg.penup()
    px,py   = 0,0
    for dx,dy in faces[face]:
        rx,ry = dx*dotSize+dotSize/2+offset,dy*dotSize+dotSize/2+offset
        tg.forward(rx-px)
        tg.left(90)
        tg.forward(ry-py)
        tg.right(90)
        px,py = rx,ry
        tg.dot(dotSize*1.5,color if face else 'white')
    tg.goto(x,y)
```

*`dice(n)` draws a dice from its bottom left corner with `n` a the number of dots. `dice(0)` erases the dice by drawing over it in white. [EDIT] updated code to allow dice to be drawn at any angle (based on current heading).*

Demo:

```
tg.left(12)  # dice angle
tg.speed(0)
tg.penup()
tg.backward(175)
dice(6)
tg.forward(125)
dice(5)
tg.forward(125)
dice(4)
tg.backward(250)
tg.right(90)
tg.forward(125)
tg.left(90)
dice(3)
tg.forward(125)
dice(2)
tg.forward(125)
dice(1)
```